# How to construct wildcard type in Scala macro?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, existential-type

I am unable to find out how to programatically construct existential types in Scala macros.

For example, let's assume that I have a `ClassSymbol` that represents a class `C[T]` that has one type parameter.

Now, how do I programatically construct the type `C[_ <: java.lang.Number]` ?

In particular, I have no idea how to use the `ExistentialType` constructor object. Looking at its signature:

```
def apply(quantified: List[Symbol], underlying: Type): ExistentialType
```

What do I pass as `quantified`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you need to create quantified symbols yourself, setting their signatures manually. Here's an abridged and adapted version of what `-Ymacro-debug-lite` printed when I compiled `typeOf[C[_ <: Number]]`. Maybe Jason or Paul know a shortcut that avoids creating symbols manually, but I'm not sure the one exists in the public API.

```
class C[T]

object Test extends App {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
  val c = typeOf[C[_]].typeSymbol
  val targ = build.newNestedSymbol(NoSymbol, newTypeName("_$1"), NoPosition, build.flagsFromBits(34359738384L), false)
  build.setTypeSignature(targ, TypeBounds(typeOf[Nothing], typeOf[Number]))
  println(ExistentialType(List(targ), TypeRef(c.owner.asClass.thisPrefix, c, List(TypeRef(NoPrefix, targ, Nil)))))
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although I'm not sure it will work with `NoSymbol` as owner. I recall trying something like this and getting some crashes.

Comment: And to make that code snippet a little more clear, the flags are actually `DEFERRED` | `EXISTENTIAL`. The latter is unfortunately not available in public API.

Comment: Jason suggests `typer.packSymbols(sym.typeParams, sym.tpe)` (that'd require a cast to get to `c.callsiteTyper), and then if you need to modify the type bounds of the underscore, use `setTypeSignature` of existential type's quantifiers.